# level picker in JavaScript API v3 for indoor maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-indoor-maps

I'm doing an offline mapping of my school building. One of the buildings have 9 floors. Just started to test and put two ground Overlays that way:

layer1 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay('images/2floor.svg', layerBounds);
layer2 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay('images/1floor.svg', layerBounds);

In other words, I've placed the two layers in the same spot.

I believed that when I increase zoom in the area, the floor picker would be shown, but that doesn't happen.

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: can you post a complete example so we can figure out what is wrong? a plunkr or jsfiddle would be awesome!

Comment: We need to see an example to get a better understanding of your error. In the mean time you can read these links https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=it#indoor_maps, https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(boolean), and https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1711534?ref_topic=3100918&p=gmm_guidelines&rd=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The V3 version of javascript GroundOverlay does not support what you want to do.  Google Maps will just lay the second GroundOverlay over the first, and the first will never show.

With the upcoming demise of Google Maps Engine, and because we had a need to show different imagery at different zoom levels plus non-rectangular satellite imagery, we wrote a GroundOverlayEX javascript class for Google Maps API V3.  It does everything the Google Earth version of GroundOverlay does (including image rotation, non-rectangular images, drawing order, support for switching images at different zoom levels, etc).

The class is up on GitHub at https://github.com/azmikemm/GroundOverlayEX
There is complete API documentation there too (documentation.txt). This is a recent coding effort.

If you want to see a working example of the class in action, you can visit 
https://sites.google.com/site/issearthatnight/. That Google Map is showing 100s of GroundOverlays drapped over North America and at the default zoom is showing low resolution images from NASA.  If you zoom in, all the GroundOverlayEX objects auto-switch to high resolution images from NASA.

The zoom-switching is completely configurable in the class, and can have as many different per-zoom-level images as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the Indoor level picker of Maps, you need a processed floor plan by google.

To do this, go to (your plan will be visible by all on GMaps) :

https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

A simple GroundOverlay is just a layer, the only possibility to do that is to create buttons for changing floor...

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Leaflet with the leaflet-indoor  library (https://github.com/cbaines/leaflet-indoor) to do that.This is an example of what I want to do: http://cbaines.net/projects/osm/leaflet-indoor/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I'm using Leaflet with the leaflet-indoor  library (https://github.com/cbaines/leaflet-indoor) to do that.

This is an example of what I want to do: http://cbaines.net/projects/osm/leaflet-indoor/examples/

Still accepting help or advice on this subject...